# How can I create permission overrides to mute a user in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Instead of using a mute role, I want to be able to create permission overrides to change permissions for users in every channel in the server to not be able to say anything. I, however, don't know how to do this, so does anybody know the way to create permission overrides, so that I can mute a user using my discord.py bot?
[image: notsobot permission overrides]

Above is an example of NotSoBot doing it to mute a user, how can I replicate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly deny the send messages permission to the user/role that assigns it to. This only works if the send messages permission was explicitly accepted in other roles. The code I use currently checks if you have the rule `__muted__`, and deletes your message if you do:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild:
        if '__muted__' in [role.name for role in message.author.roles]:
            try:
                await message.delete()
                await message.author.send(f'\u274c You are muted in **{message.guild.name}**!')
                return
            except discord.errors.Forbidden:
                pass
```